# Find Duplicated record for any 3 common attributes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

In my RoR Project, there is a Customer model with 10 attributes. Now I want to find those customers that have at-least any three common attributes. How can I make this query efficiently?

Probably it's a solution:

```
Customer.select([:first_name,:last_name,:language]).
         group(:first_name,:last_name,:language).having("count(*) > 1")
```

But this solution required too many combination to check. Please help with a better solution.

Thanks! In Advance.

Comment: No, this is a different question. The above is where we know exactly these two given columns match. This question asks if any two out of three possible columns match

Comment: @Taryn East: Unfortunately this solution does not solve my problem. Because I expect those customer who have at-least any three common attributes. Anyway, Thanks, for your comment.

Comment: i have not suggested a solution at all. I voted against closing and gave my reason for not voting-to-close-as-duplicate. My comment was for the guy who voted to close as duplicate, not for you - sorry - i don't have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I can come up with so far. Also not an SQL solution.

```
# Arrange a 3-items combination of columns, removed id and timestamps
triplets = Customer.column_names.reject {|column| column == "id" || column == "created_at" || column == "updated_at"}.combination(3).to_a

#Group All records by same item values for each 3-items combination
all = Customer.all
res = triplets.map do|t| 
  all.to_a.group_by {|c| [ {t[0] => c.send(t[0].to_sym)}, { t[1] => c.send(t[1].to_sym) }, {t[2] => c.send(t[2].to_sym)} ]} 
end  
# removed combinations with only 1 record
final_result = res.map {|h1| h1.reject { |k, v| v.count <= 1}}

# There you have customer with 3 attributes common combinations
```